# using gnu find command to match subpath with slashes in it

Tags: bash

using the linux find command, how do i match any subdirectory having the string '/ip/axi_pcie_0/' in the path?

example find output:

```
./rtl/vlog/project_1/project_1.srcs/sources_1/ip/axi_pcie_0
./rtl/vlog/vivado.2020.a02/vivado.2020.a02.srcs/sources_1/ip/axi_pcie_0
./rtl/vlog/vivado.2020.a02/vivado.2020.a02.srcs/sources_1/ip/axi_pcie_0/axi_pcie_0
./rtl/vlog/vivado.2020.a03/vivado.2020.srcs/sources_1/ip/axi_pcie_0
./rtl/vlog/vivado.2020.a03/vivado.2020.srcs/sources_1/ip/axi_pcie_0/axi_pcie_0
./rtl/vlog/vivado.2020.a03/vivado.2020.srcs/sources_1/ip/axi_pcie_0_1/axi_pcie_0
./rtl/vlog/vivado.2020.a04/a04_fpga.srcs/sources_1/ip/axi_pcie_0
./rtl/vlog/vivado.2020.a04/a04_fpga.srcs/sources_1/ip/axi_pcie_0/axi_pcie_0
```

I tried:

```
$ find -name ip/axi_pcie_0
```

and it doesn't work...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find  -type d | egrep "ip/axi_pcie_0$"
```

Comment: Is this the solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
find -path "*/ip/axi_pcie_0*"
```